# How to get 32 bit JRE path on 64 bit Linux with 64 bit browser and 64 bit java plugin

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, applet, 32bit-64bit

My application consists of three components:

1. Applet
2. Java program (myapp.jar)
3. JNI library (myjni.so)

Please note that JNI library is built for 32 bit.   On 32 bit OS, applet uses `java.home` property to get the JRE path. Once applet gets  JRE path, it launches JAR like this

```
JRE-path myapp.jar
```

Now I need to run this application on 64 bit Linux.  Here I have two options:

1. Build JNI library for 64 bit. 
   This is not possible as all depended libraries needs to build for 64 bit. ( This is a constraint at my end)
2. Ask users to install 32 bit JVM
   Now problem is how to get the 32 bit JRE path as `java.home` property gives the 64 bit JRE path. ( Because browser and plugins are 64 bit).  One option is to use `update-alternatives –list java` command to get all JRE installations path.   Then for each installation path, run `JRE-path -d32 –version` command to see whether it supports 32 bit JVM

   - If it supports 32 bit JVM, use that JRE path to launch JAR file
   - If none of the java installations support 32 bit JVM, show message to install 32 bit JVM

Question:

1. Is there any problem for above mentioned solution? (I need to use this solution on Ubuntu, Redhat and OpenSuse)
2. Is there better solution to get 32 JRE path on 64 bit Linux?

Comment: How do you push the native lib to the clients? I suppose your applet is signed with a trusted certificate, correct?

Comment: Yes applet is signed with trusted certificate. Native lib is pushed to client using java delivery mechanism

Answer (score 1):

Use option 1. Build both a 32bit and 64bit JNI library and load the relevant .so based on being on a 32-bit or 64-bit VM.

You can use the `sun.arch.data.model` system property for the Sun JDK

You can use the `com.ibm.vm.bitmode` for the IBM websphere VM

Or look for the substring `64` in the `os.arch` system property (it's x86_64/amd64 on 64bit intel based VMs)

As you cannot build a 64bit variant of the `.so` and all it's dependent `.a` and `.so` files (this is actually good software configuration management practice), then the following shell script should be a good effort. If at the end of calling it the script exits with `66`, then there is no valid 32bit java

```
#!/bin/bash -p

# attempt to find a 32bit VM
# uses a dummy class file (it's just an empty file)

trap 'rm -f /tmp/testclass$$.class /tmp/jlocations.$$' EXIT HUP

touch /tmp/testclass$$.class

tryj() {
    while read java; do
        errout=$($java -cp /tmp -d32 testclass$$ 2>&1)
        if grep -q 'java.lang.ClassFormatError' <<<$errout; then
            # good VM - run with this
            rm -f /tmp/testclass$$.class /tmp/jlocations.$$
            # echo $java "$@"
            exec $java "$@"
        fi
    done </tmp/jlocations.$$
    return 1
}

# try update-alternatives - debian/ubuntu
update-alternatives --list java > /tmp/jlocations.$$ 2>/dev/null

tryj "$@"

# Try alternatives - redhat
alternatives --list java > /tmp/jlocations.$$ 2>/dev/null

tryj "$@"

# then try locate - generic linux/unix
locate java | grep 'bin/java$' > /tmp/jlocations.$$

tryj "$@"

# if we had no luck, then use find - this will be sloooooooooow
find / -wholename '*/bin/java' >/tmp/jlocations.$$ 2>/dev/null
tryj "$@"

exit 66
```

Comment: Option 1 cannot be used. This is because myjni.so depends on some other static and shared libs. So i need to compile so modules for 64 bit. Again those modules another set of libraries etc. In short, I need to build whole stack for 64 bit.

Comment: Then option 1 was not really an option. On my ubuntu system I don't even have an option to install a 32bit variant of the jre - I have to install it manually, which means that it doesn't appear in the `update-alternatives` output. I'll add to the answer with an option that uses a shell script leveraging `locate` to try to find a copy of java, and failing that to fall back to using find